# useState variable is called before useEffect API call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, fetch-api

From what I understand `useEffect` hook runs last as a sideEffect. I am attempting to console log `data.main.temp`. I can understand that it doesn't know what that is yet, because it is fetching the data from the API in the `useEffect` hook which runs after.

How would I be able to access or console log `data.main.temp` AFTER the API call? (I feel like `setTimout` is the cheating way?)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Button from "../UI/Button";
import styles from "./Weather.module.css";
import moment from "moment";
import Card from "../UI/Card";

export default function Weather() {
  //State Management//
  const [lat, setLat] = useState([]);
  const [long, setLong] = useState([]);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  //openWeather API key
  const key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      //get coordinates//
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
        setLat(position.coords.latitude);
        setLong(position.coords.longitude);
      });
      //fetch openWeather api//
      await fetch(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather/?lat=${lat}&lon=${long}&units=metric&APPID=${key}`)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((result) => {
          setData(result);
          console.log(result);
        });
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [lat, long]);


//Examples of what I want, they run too early before api//
console.log(data.main.temp);
const Farenheit = data.main.temp * 1.8 + 32;

  return (
    <Card>
      {typeof data.main != "undefined" ? (
        <div className={`${styles.weatherContainer} ${styles.clouds}`}>
          <h2>Weather</h2>
          <p>{data.name}</p>
          <p>{data.main.temp * 1.8 + 32} &deg;F</p>
          <p>{data.weather[0].description}</p>
          <hr></hr>
          <h2>Date</h2>
          <p>{moment().format("dddd")}</p>
          <p>{moment().format("LL")}</p>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div></div>
      )}
    </Card>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right, the effect function is run after the first render which means you need to wait somehow until your api call is done. One common way to do so is to introduce another state flag which indicate whether the data is available or not.

Another thing which does not follow react good practices is the fact that you're effect function does more than one thing.

I also added trivial error handling and cleaned up mixed promises and async await

here is your refactored code

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Button from "../UI/Button";
import styles from "./Weather.module.css";
import moment from "moment";
import Card from "../UI/Card";

//openWeather API key
const key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

export default function Weather() {
  //State Management//
  const [lat, setLat] = useState();
  const [long, setLong] = useState();
  const [data, setData] = useState();
  const [error, setError] = useState();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
      setLat(position.coords.latitude);
      setLong(position.coords.longitude);
    });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      if (lat && long && key) {
        try {
          setLoading(true);
          const response = await fetch(
            `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather/?lat=${lat}&lon=${long}&units=metric&APPID=${key}`
          );
          const data = await response.json();
          setData(data);
          setLoading(false);
        } catch (err) {
          setError(err);
          setLoading(false);
        }
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [lat, long]);

  if (error) {
    return <div>some error occurred...</div>;
  }

  return (
    <Card>
      {loading || !data ? (
        <div>loading...</div>
      ) : (
        <div className={`${styles.weatherContainer} ${styles.clouds}`}>
          <h2>Weather</h2>
          <p>{data.name}</p>
          <p>{data.main.temp * 1.8 + 32} &deg;F</p>
          <p>{data.weather[0].description}</p>
          <hr></hr>
          <h2>Date</h2>
          <p>{moment().format("dddd")}</p>
          <p>{moment().format("LL")}</p>
        </div>
      )}
    </Card>
  );
}
```

Comment: I see, very thorough. I appreciate taking the time to refactor the code and I didn't know that about using separate useEffects!

Comment: One question though, the first useEffect will only run once if I am right, and since the users lcoation may change wouldnt I need an array dependency in there?

Comment: <p>{Math.round(parseFloat(data.main.temp) * 1.8 + 32)} &deg;F</p> by the way, if anybody needs a conversion to Farenhiet here you go

Comment: Yes, the empty dependency array means that the effect will run only once (on mount). The getCurrentPosition API is kind of "one time" operation so it makes sense to put it into "onMount" hook.

But if you wuold like to watch user location you need to use `navigator.geolocation.watchPosition` API inside the hook. This API let's you subscribe to position changes. But important thing to note is that you must use effect clean up (function which is returned from the effect) in order to unregister the handler 

`return () => navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(id);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use another useEffect, which depends on changing the data state

```
useEfect(() => {
  if (data) {
    // do something with data
  }
}, [data])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple function and call it in your API call response and pass in the `data` directly from the api response, that way you will have access to the data immediately there's a response.

E.g

```
...
.then((result) => {
  setData(result);
  getDataValue(result) // this function will be called when the response comes in and you can use the value for anything
  console.log(result);
});
```

METHOD 2:

You can use a useEffect hook to monitor changes in the data state, so that whenever there's an update on that state, you can use the value to do whatever you want. This is my less preferred option.

```
useEffect(() => {
   //this hook will run whenever data changes, the initial value of data will however be what the initial value of the state is

console.log(data) //initial value = [] , next value => response from API
},[data])
```

Comment: thank you! I do like the concept of option one yes